# WWW::Selenium to capture component refresh

Tags: perl, selenium

I am writing a perl script using `WWW::Selenium` module to automate a website.
I am not at all a web development guy and have no idea about web technologies.

Let me try to explain the issue in layman terms.

I am dealing with a webpage, which has an order form with a button.
When I click the button, there is no page submit, but the button label changes.

Say for eg, the button goes through these changes when clicked multiple times.

Get Quote --> Order --> Confirm Order

Each time I click the button, there is no page refresh, but the button label keeps changing as above.

The `id` of the button is the same throughout, only the `class` changes.

How can I do this in WWW::Selenium?

Presently I am using `wait_for_page_to_load(5000)` after each click.
But the click is not having any effect on the label and I get error that timed out after 5000s.

Should I be using some other function to wait?

Comment: I've not used the WWW::Selenium though I have used Selenium with Rails testing.  Since you are not reloading the page there is no point to waiting for that.  Can't you just check for the new class after clicking?  What are you using to change the class?

Comment: All the classes are present always. For each action the corresponding class gets enabled. This is not my website.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
$sel->wait_for_text_present_ok("Your text","time to wait","The message to display if this fails");
```

and an example below-

```
$sel->wait_for_text_present_ok("Order Confirmed","9000","The order was successfully placed");
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. This website has all the text present always. Only thing is, after each action each class gets enabled.

Comment: O so u tried it out and dint work? Anyways next recommendation switch to Webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use

```
$class = $sel->get_attribute($attribute_locator)
```

where the $attribute_locator is the button@class with button being the element locator that you clicked.  Check if $class is the class you expect.